# Is there a piece that is a plate 4x4 with 1 center knob?

Tags: piece-information

I can make something similar with a 2x2 with center knob and stone surrounding pieces, but I really want it in one single piece.

Answer (score 6):

No there isn’t such a plate (yet). Your proposed alternative is the best way to create a 4x4 surface with a single centered stud.

Answer (score 6):

The closest I could think of in 4 x 4 size would be [Turntable 4 x 4 Square Base, Locking](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=61485#T=C). It doesn't feature a stud in the center and has this ring on top, unfortunately. However, depending on your use case center hole still could be used to attach whatever you are building.

[image]

Comment: Can a 1×1 round piece fit in that ring? Looks like one might.

Comment: @KRyan that whole is bit too small for 1x1 round plate. 1x1 cone, however, could be used from underneath to get a stud on top. Technic, Axle 3 with Stud (6587) could also be used to get a stud on top. All of these need some sort of the base underneath the turntable base though. Not sure what does OP use on top but there are other than "stud" options of "axle", "pin" and "bar" connections passed through that hole.

Comment: I initially tried placing a piece on the hole, that does not work. I then started trying to do what @Alex suggested by placing pieces underneath. That seems to work, but not sure if it is practical for my problem. Neat though.

Comment: @prolink007 which piece or structure you are looking to place on top?

Comment: I am wanting to use it as a square on a chess board i am making. The center knob would be used to hold a flat piece in place that is the base of the chess pieces. This solution would not work for me, since it would look strange on the board. But it is a potential solution for a center knob on a 4x4.